# I would like to be able to typedef a color in html, is that possible?

Tags: html, colors, typedef

Just a simple example, I want to do something like

```
yellow1= #FFFF0A;

<p style="background-color:yellow1">
some text
</p>
```

is something like this possible with html?

Comment: Such a nice question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875852/define-colors-as-variables-in-css

Comment: why you want to do it?

Comment: this question is already asked in stack overflow itself.Upvote for this question???? duplicate one

Comment: With html - hard, but... with a little help of jquery, maybe... http://jsfiddle.net/AC6HV/28/ However, i would use much better solutions, already mentioned above.. :)