# Create CSS Variable out of normal command?

Tags: css, css-variables

I´m working on a website with a CMS tool. I want to change the background of an image preview, which is in css code this:

```
.mfp-container {
background: rgb(222, 222, 222);
}
```

So it's a really basic code, I just want to adjust the color. My CMS Tool works with css variables and I never worked with those and really have no idea how to get a variable out of this.

Does someone know how to get one out of this basic code? Or is there any formula to "convert" it?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, that's not how CSS vars work. However if you just want to change the background and `mfp-container` is the selector you're given then you can just override with your own css like `.mfp-container { background: red !important }`

Comment: You want to permanently create a CSS variable out of the RGB color value and then call it? Or were you under the impression that `rgb(222, 222, 222)` *was* a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I define colors as variables in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875852/how-can-i-define-colors-as-variables-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp

It's RGB colour code, so you just enter wanted amount of red 0-255, green 0-255, blue 0-255 separated by commas

To use this color as variable you would declare it like this:

```
--variable-name:rgb(222,222,222)
```

And then use it later in CSS like this

```
background:var(--variable-name)
```