# Derived CSS Values

Tags: css

Is it possible to reference a value in one part of a stylesheet in another part? For example, say I want to set the CSS `top` value for a div with `position:absolute` to match the height of another element, is there a way to do that? Is it possible to say, in effect:

```
.div1 {
    height: 50px;
}

.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: <height value of div1>
}
```

Comment: javascript for the win

Comment: If you have a fixed value on `.div1`, why not just add also that fixed value to `.div2`?

Comment: Do you mean adynamically sized element (flexible content etc) or do you mean to just not write the same number twice for the same height?

Comment: I had originally marked this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487/create-a-variable-in-css-file-for-use-within-that-css-file, but I guess this isn't really asking directly about variables within CSS files so I've reopened it.

Comment: Because the aim is that if I have an enormous stylesheet and I decide, in the future, to change the height of div1, everything else moves accordingly, rather than me having to change many values throughout the stylesheet.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly reading the OPs comment, I would say that you were right at first - for this being a duplicate.

Comment: I see, then yes, SASS is the answer

Comment: If you're trying to create a layout: avoid absolute positioning and avoid `height` property (what if there's more content or if user needs to zoom - text method, not graphical). If `div` are on the same line, you can use CSS table layout with `display: table(-cell)`; they'll have the same height automagically (do NOT use HTML tables for layout of course)

Comment: @Vucko I dispute that this is a duplicate question of the one referenced. My question displays no knowledge of CSS variables. The answer may be to use CSS variables, thus making the answer to each question the same, but the question is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to take a look at something like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org).

You can use calculations with those (SASS example here):

```
$averageHeightDivs : 50;
```

and do things like

```
.div2 {
    height: 2*$averageHeightDivs;
}
```

But better you would use mixins:

```
@mixin divSize($factor, $width, $height) {
  height: $factor * $height;
  width: $factor * $width;
}

.div1 {
  @include divSize(1, 10, 20);
}

.div2 {
  @include divSize(2, 10, 20);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how exactily SASS or LESS can do this? I'm assuming you dont mean with a variable?

Comment: I would use variables. Is there a reason you cannot?

Comment: No thats perfectly fine, I assumed the OP meant the height of the second element wasnt known. maybe I miss read, I'd just assume that if the value WAS known, then why not use it.

Comment: Having seen the updated comments You have the best answer, I did get the wrong end of it and assume the OP meant css being aware of an element dimensions

Comment: I updated the answer a bit. Fixed some typos and added an example. What is the downvote for? Would really appreciate to know what it is about, we are all here to learn.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is one of weak points of CSS. Luckily, there are some nice extension to CSS, which are easy to use and solve many common problems.

Have a look at these:

[Less](http://lesscss.org/)

[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using sass  variables. Check out http://sass-lang.com/guide. Basically you set the values of each variable you want to reuse and then call it when needed.