# Best CSS generator language?

Tags: css, maintainability

Reusing values in CSS (particularly colors) has always been a problem for me when it comes to maintaining that CSS. What are the best tools for creating variables, or generally improving maintainability with CSS?

Answer (score 3):

See the answers to the following questions

- [Create a variable in .CSS file for use within that .CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487/create-a-variable-in-css-file-for-use-within-that-css-file)
- [Avoiding repeated constants in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170/avoiding-repeated-constants-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Sass](https://sass-lang.com) and think it's great.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had the chance to use it on a project yet, but if you happen to be using PHP for your backend, [Turbine](http://turbine.peterkroener.de/) looks promising.