# How to use numbers from a js file in the css sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use the numbers claculated in js in the css sheet.

I have this js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//js cut out here

//document.write('<p>Your viewport width is '+viewportwidth+'x'+viewportheight+'</p>');
alert('<p>Your viewport width is '+viewportwidth+'x'+viewportheight+'</p>');

//-->
</script>
```

The has the alert where viewportwidth shows the width of the browser and viewportheight shows the height of the browser window. I want to use those number is the style sheet like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body, 
#page {
    width:   100%;
    height:  100%;
    margin:  0;
}
#map_canvas {
    width:   (viewportwidth-200) px;
    height:  viewportheight;
}
#sidebar {
    width:200px;
    height:viewportheight px;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>
```

Is is possible to do this?

I found this: [Parse Javascript variable to CSS variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424824/pass-javascript-variable-to-css-variables)

but I'm having trouble getting it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the CSS stylesheet with JS. However, you can override the stylesheet by applying inline style to elements or by appending a new `<style>` tag after the original stylesheet.

Using your `viewportheight` variable...

**Option One:**

```
myEl.style.height = viewportheight + 'px';
```

**Option Two:**

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css'; style.rel = 'stylesheet';
style.innerHTML = '#map_canvas { height: ' + viewportheight + 'px; }';
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Further, [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) might be of some interest.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I run the javascript file before the stylesheet; would it be possible to make a string from that script that then becomes the css I use for the page?

Answer (score 4):

You can modify a specific element's styling using [JavaScript](http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/javascript/modify-css-with-javascript):

```
document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.width = "800px";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to use jQuery, this is your best option.  The `.width()` function will give you the current width of an object, including the window and can also be used to set the width of an object.  You can also set up a handler on the `.resize()` event to also continually resize an object when a resize even happens on an object, including window.

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQJwz/3/) demoing the code.

In the example, I set the size on document load, then set up a handler on the window resize event to keep adjusting the size of the one `div` I have in the example.  Here's the JavaScript/jQuery code that does the actual resizing for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    adjustCanvasSize();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustCanvasSize();
    });
});

function adjustCanvasSize() {
    var win = $(window);
    var width = win.width();
    var height = win.height();   
    var canvas = $('#map_canvas');
    canvas.width(width - 200);
    canvas.height(height);
}
```

Comment: To say that jQuery is the best option is a bit deceptive.  Don't get me wrong, I like jQuery, but this is completely possible with simple JavaScript and no need to add the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

For now, the best you can do is setting the style in JavaScript (and updating it whenever the viewport changes). CSS3 does add `vw` and `vh` units that let you specify lengths relative to the viewport width and height respectively. Combined with the `calc` function, you can do what you want. This is really just for future reference though, since both of those are experimental and not supported by older browsers yet (See http://caniuse.com/viewport-units and http://caniuse.com/calc).

Also, keep in mind that `vw` and `vh` are percentages, so the whole width is `100vw`.

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body, 
#page {
    width:   100%;
    height:  100%;
    margin:  0;
}
#map_canvas {
    width:  -webkit-calc(100vw - 200px);
    width:  -moz-calc(100vw - 200px);
    width:  calc(100vw - 200px);
    height: 100vh;
}
#sidebar {
    width:    200px;
    height:   100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```