# How to use variable in CSS?

Tags: css, variables, global-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a variable in .CSS file for use within that .CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487/create-a-variable-in-css-file-for-use-within-that-css-file)

I heard about that we can declare/define variable in CSS and use them like global variables like this:

```
@nice-blue: #5B83AD;

#header { color: @nice-blue; }
```

So anyone knows how to use them?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/People/Bos/CSS-variables

Comment: @gavenkoa nobody forces you to use them

Comment: The duplicate page is also a duplicate.  Try this instead:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170/avoiding-repeated-constants-in-css

Comment: With respect to CSS variables, they are now supported by all the major browsers, minus Microsoft edge. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For that you need to use [**Less**](http://lesscss.org/) or [**Sass**](http://sass-lang.com/) which are CSS Dynamic languages.

here's some [comparison](https://web.archive.org/web/20130122062617/http://wrangl.com/sass-v-less) between both technologies.

Comment: dead links in this answer.

Comment: Also you could take a look at the CSS Variable Shim @ http://cssvariables.com

Comment: Fixed dead link using Wayback Machine. (Page is slightly broken, but still useful.)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use something like SASS

http://sass-lang.com/#variables

or Less

http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 4):

There is a language written on top of CSS which make use of variables like you asked, it's called [LessCSS](http://www.lesscss.org)