# Multiple Code in a CSS Variable

Tags: css, variables

I think it's a easy question, but i found nothing in google which helps me.

I've the following code:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Now i use it in more than 1 CSS class. And when i want to change the box-sizing, i don't want to change it in all statements. So i want to use some CSS variable. But i don't find a example to define more than one statement in a CSS variable. Any solution?

What i've already tried:

```
@boxsizing: 
(
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
)
```

Comment: CSS and variables? There are no variables, constants or any other place-holding mechanisms in CSS. However, you can use the same rules on many selectors by grouping them with the comma-separator `,`.

Comment: CSS don't support variables. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247202/how-to-use-variable-in-css?rq=1

Comment: It depends the statement, you should be more specific. In CSS it's called media queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Saw some code with variables. But now i know it was developed with LESS or something. Sorry for this stupid question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vanilla CSS does not use variables in the way you intend them to use.

For such behavior you need other tools to generate (valid) CSS out of dynamic code files. Examples include the following:

- [LESS](http://www.lesscss.de/)
- [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: Ah! Also heard about LESS. But never read an article about it! Thank you! +1 &, when i can, accepted.

Answer (score 2):

CSS has no such thing as variables. You can make your code more DRY by defining the same styles for several selectors, for instance:

```
.boxsizing, #my_element, div, a.foobar {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Also tried. But anything doesn't work. So i want to start to develop with variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [SCSS](http://compass-style.org) to do that.