# Is it possible to use variables to hold property values in CSS?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

In a CSS file, is there a way to use variables for colors (or other properties)? For example, say I have the following code:

```
#container1 {
    background: #ff0000;
}

#container2 {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

If I decided to change the red color (#ff0000) throughout my site to something else, I would need to find and replace all instances of "#FF0000" in the StyleSheet. If I have multiple StyleSheets throughout the site, this could become annoying.

Is it not possible to do something like this instead:

```
#container1 {
    background: redColor;
}

#container2 {
    background: redColor;
}

.redColor {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

I know that I could reference "container1" with class "redColor" but I'm wondering if I can use variables so that I could reference the value for other properties like font color, etc...

Thanks for any help!

Andrew.

Comment: Native CSS can't do this.

Comment: @Adrift - LessCss seems cool but I'm not convinced adding a new library is a wise idea for something like this. I guess if it's not possible without an external library, then it's not possible...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variable in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247202/how-to-use-variable-in-css)

Comment: which is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487/create-a-variable-in-css-file-for-use-within-that-css-file

Answer (score 1):

Sass or Less Would add this feature and much more.

http://sass-lang.com/

http://lesscss.org/

Comment: Sass/Less can be translated to CSS via build scripts so this is not really adding weight to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Pekka has stated it is not possible to do this with CSS.

But, it is possible to do it with [LESS Variables](http://lesscss.org/#-variables) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) as @Adrift has stated.

In LESS for example:

```
@nice-blue: #5B83AD;
@light-blue: (@nice-blue + #111);

#header { color: @light-blue; }
```

And SASS is quite similar.