# CSS Variable assign

Tags: css, variables

Is it possible to use variables within a CSS document, possibly by using Javascript?

For example if I have an overall variable "colorOne" assigned to "#ffffff".

Is it then possible to to call "colorOne" later? e.g. "color: colorOne;"?

I could use find and replace to replace instances but this becomes very tedious, is there an alternative?

Comment: Try to look for "CSS preprocessors" with google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247202/how-to-use-variable-in-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a preprocessor, for instance: http://lesscss.org/

What this enables you to do is write your CSS like this

```
@colorOne: #FFFFFF;

.main_links {
  color: @colorOne;
}
h2 {
  color: @colorOne;
}
```

and the output once it's compiled will be

```
.main_links {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

There are more reasons to use LESS than just assigning variables, it's powerful and allows you to do a lot more, like nested styles, have a look at the documentation: http://lesscss.org/#synopsis

Answer (score 4):

In pure css - NO!

But you can use many tools that allow to do it and compile css for you:

1. Less CSS - http://lesscss.org/
2. Compass - http://compass-style.org/ (to compile SASS/SCSS http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 2):

**This is not possible with pure CSS.**

However, you can use a third party library, such as [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/), to achieve this:

```
@nice-blue: #5B83AD;

#header { color: @nice-blue; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont forget SASS too. 
http://sass-lang.com

Syntatically Awesome Stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use variables in pure CSS, but aside from things like LESS, there is another way (*not the cleanest admittedly, but it works...sort of*).

**Set up classes which represent your variables:**

```
.color-black {
    color: #000000;
}

.color-red {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

**You can then specify multiple classes against an element:**

```
<div class="some-class other-class color-black"></div>
<div class="some-class other-class color-red"></div>
```

Thereafter, whenever you change the value in `color-black`, or `color-red`, this will change the color across all elements using that class.

As I've stated, it's not the cleanest way to do things, and can lead to bloated html/css, but it can have it's uses...say for example in a testing environment if you're testing color schemes / designs.

**Note:** One other thing to mention is that using this method allows you to swap out classes dynamically *using javascript*, as you have mentioned in your question.

**Example (with jQuery)**

```
$("#MyDiv").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("color-red").addClass("color-black");
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("color-black").addClass("color-red");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use something like [`LESS`](http://lesscss.org/#synopsis):

This would allow you to use [variables](http://lesscss.org/#-variables):

```
@colorOne: #5B83AD;

#header { color: @colorOne; }
```